# Can SQL SUM() function take an expression as argument?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I'm using SQLite database and I'm wondering whether I'm allowed to write queries as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(column1 * column2)
FROM my_table;
```

I googled but references say that SUM function is has the following format:

```
SUM([DISTINCT|ALL] column)
```

And my question is: does `column` mean actually column or does it allow expressions (like above) too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use an expression like the one you mentioned, if the datatype of both columns allow it.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use a table expression:

```
SELECT SUM(Calc)
FROM (
SELECT Column1 * Column2 AS 'Calc'
FROM My_Table) t
```

I don't have SQLite but checking the docs indicates this should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! Your variant looks fine but assume situation when I have `GROUP BY` clause, e.g. `SELECT SUM(column1*column2) FROM my_table GROUP_BY column3`. I don't see any way to convert such a query to your variant.

Comment: @tonytony It's a moot point since apparently your original code should work fine.